# Newbie at Python (greater than but less than; return

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cookiedict = {'banana':5, 'blueberries':5, 'jerky':5}

def cookies():
    return input('Which of the cookies do you want to eat?')
def number():
    return int(input('How many cookies do you want to eat?'))

cookies = cookies ()
number = number ()

while True:
    if cookiedict[cookies] >0 <=5:
        cookiedict[cookies] -= number
        print ('You ate {} of the {} cookies'.format(number,cookies))
    elif cookiedict[cookies] >=6:
        print ('Game Over!!! You ate too much!!!')
        break
    else:
        print ('Incorrect Input. Try again...')
```

This is my second day. I'm using a combo of udemy course and youtube videos. You probably know what I'm trying to accomplish by looking at the code. If you eat more than the available cookies you lose. There are only 5 for each.

```
if cookiedict[cookies] >0 <=5:
       cookiedict[cookies] -= number
        print ('You ate {} of the {} cookies'.format(number,cookies))
```

I have no idea why this does not work. It keeps outputting the print no matter what number I type in, even though I think I'm telling it to only print when greater than 0 and equal or less than 5.

Also, am I doing this part correct? It seems like it shouldn't work for some reason but it is accepting input.

```
def cookies():
    return input('Which of the cookies do you want to eat?')
def number():
    return int(input('How many cookies do you want to eat?'))

cookies = cookies ()
number = number ()
```

Thanks for any help. I've spent the last couple of hours playing with this and can not get it to work!!

Comment: you meant this `if cookiedict[cookies] >0 and  cookiedict[cookies] <=5:`  ?

Comment: simplest way in python would be, `0 < cookiedict[cookies]  < 6` ... Also, since multiple functions are there, trying using a class rather than static functions .... good luck with learning and welcome to python! :)

Comment: `x > 0 <= 5` is equivalent to `(x > 0) and (0 <= 5)`.  Since `(0 <= 5)` is always true, the entire expression is equivalent to `x > 0`.  To achieve your intent, you would need to write `0 < x <= 5`, which is equivalent to `(0 < x) and (x <= 5)`.

Comment: You are comparing the value from the dict rather than the input you are taking. Good Luck with your learing and welcome to python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always printing because you are not comparing the number input but the number of available cookies. You need to compare the input number and print if the input number is `<=5 and >0`.
Do This:-

```
while True:
    if 0 < number <= 5:
        cookiedict[cookies] -= number
        print ('You ate {} of the {} cookies'.format(number,cookies))
    elif number >= 6:
        print ('Game Over!!! You ate too much!!!')
        break
    else:
        print ('Incorrect Input. Try again...')
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: `0 < number <= 5` is a better way to express this in Python

Answer (score 1):

`x >0 <=5` is short for `x > 0 and 0 <= 5`. Since 0 is always less than 5, the second part is always true and you end up only comparing `>0`.

What you want is: `0 < x <= 5`, which means `0 < x and x <= 5`.