# Assigning HEX value based on a variable float

Tags: python, hex, discord.py

## IN SHORT

I am confused, I am trying to assign a hex colour based on an integer value, basically like this:

```py
_total_wn8 = int(input("WN8 value: "))

if 0 > _total_wn8 <= 300:
    color = "000" # Black
    print(f"Colour = {color} (black)")
elif 300 > _total_wn8 <= 599:
    color = "cd3333" # Red
    print(f"Colour = {color} (red)")
elif 599 > _total_wn8 <= 899:
    color = "d77900" # Orange
    print(f"Colour = {color} (orange)")
elif 899 > _total_wn8 <= 1249:
    color = "d7b600" # Yellow
    print(f"Colour = {color} (yellow)")
elif 1249 > _total_wn8 <= 1599:
    color = "6d9521" # Light green
    print(f"Colour = {color} (light green)")
elif 1599 > _total_wn8 <= 1899:
    color = "4c762e" # Dark green
    print(f"Colour = {color} (dark green)")
elif 1899 > _total_wn8 <= 2349:
    color = "4a92b7" # Blue
    print(f"Colour = {color} (blue)")
elif 2349 > _total_wn8 <= 2899:
    color = "83579d" # Light purple
    print(f"Colour = {color} (light purple)")
else:
    color = "5a3175" # Dark purple
    print(f"Colour = {color} (dark purple)")

# Gives this in console:
WN8 value: 972
Colour = 6d9521 (light green)
```

But 972 is between 899 and 1249, so I expected the colour yellow
What am I doing wrong?

### Explanation:

I am making a discord bot with python (full code for command [here](https://mystb.in/LuxembourgFilesPsp.python)), I get some values from a website using BeautifulSoup (which are strings by default):

```py
_total_wn8 = int(td1[0].text.replace(',', '')) / 100 # Removing comma so I can convert to int, then dividing by 100 again
_24h_wn8 = int(td1[1].text.replace(',', '')) / 100
_30d_wn8 = int(td1[3].text.replace(',', '')) / 100

# Printing gives this for example:
971.91
2552.21
953.87
```

I have this code to assign a hex colour based on the `_total_wn8` value, so that I can use that as the embed colour (like this: `color=int(color, 16)`) in discord:

```py
if 0 > _total_wn8 <= 300:
    color = "000" # Black
elif 300 > _total_wn8 <= 599:
    color = "cd3333" # Red
elif 599 > _total_wn8 <= 899:
    color = "d77900" # Orange
elif 899 > _total_wn8 <= 1249:
    color = "d7b600" # Yellow
elif 1249 > _total_wn8 <= 1599:
    color = "6d9521" # Light green
elif 1599 > _total_wn8 <= 1899:
    color = "4c762e" # Dark green
elif 1899 > _total_wn8 <= 2349:
    color = "4a92b7" # Blue
elif 2349 > _total_wn8 <= 2899:
    color = "83579d" # Light purple
else:
    color = "5a3175" # Dark purple
```

I made that based of this colour scheme table:

[image: Colour scheme]

I am confused however, because when for example the `_total_wn8` is 972, I would expect the colour yellow, however the embed colour is light green, or if the `_total_wn8` is 2219 it makes the colour light purple, when I expected blue. Sometimes though, it does work correctly, for example when the `_wn8_total` is below 300, the colour is correctly black.

### What I have done so far:

1. I have rechecked every HEX colour value, and they are correct.
2. I have printed the color variable right after it was assigned, which
   was the the colour it was assigned, but not the correct one.
3. I have rechecked my logic and I personally do not see any problems
4. Trying it in a different python file, with [this](https://mystb.in/ManufacturingFractionFailing.python)code, which
   gives the same results!

### My question:

Is my logic off? What am I doing wrong here? I feel like there is something that I am not seeing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the less than symbol wrong in all your conditions.

You don't want `300 > _total_wn8 <= 599`, but `300 < _total_wn8 <= 599`. Notice the first comparation symbol should be `<`, not a `>`.

**Explanation**
In Python, chained comparisons expand to a series of simple comparisons with `and`s between them as you would see in other languages, so for example `300 > _total_wn8 <= 599` becomes `300 > _total_wn8 and _total_wn8 <= 599`.

If you look closely at this, you'll see it doesn't do what you want. You expect, for example, that `400` makes `300 > _total_wn8 <= 599` true, but it doesn't:

- `300 > _total_wn8` when `_total_wn8 = 400` is `300 > 400`, which is **false**.
- `_total_wn8 <= 599` when `_total_wn8 = 400` is `400 <= 500`, which is **true**.
- `false and true` is **false**.

So, the condition you have wrong is the first one, `300 > _total_wn8`. You must fix this in all your `if` statements.

Comment: Yeah.. thanks.. I guess this guy was false: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428744/12112111

Comment: @MysteriousDuck That answer is correct, but `300 > _total_wn8 <= 599` is thus equivalent to just `300 > _total_wn8`. If the variable is less than 300, it is necessarily less than 599 as well.

Comment: I've added a explanation to try to help OP understand it better.